# What is a proper design pattern of Ajax data manipulation? Js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know a couple of approaches using Ajax to manipulate database, I'm just not quite sure which one (if any) would be proper and most used so I have a couple of questions.

1. Have one url to handle all kind of requests accordingly or multiple for each specific reason?
2. Would it be better to have a single function containing Ajax request to which an object parameter can be passed to manipulated request (Url, Type, etc.) or multiple functions, each with static properties of Ajax request for specific thing?

What would be the most clean design pattern of structuring data manipulation? Thanks!

Comment: Do some reading on REST

Comment: I use one general ajax function client side, with parameters so you can reuse it for all the calls inside its own ajax module. Serverside it depends alot on which and how many different backends you have. But generally I try to only have one entry/endpoint on the server, which again, can be called with different parameters. But listen to Steve, read a bit about REST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anyone can answer this definitively without more specific information about the domain you're dealing with. It's possible that there is a case where one function could deal with multiple CRUD operations based on the parameters passed in, and a clever architecture could make decisions based on the parameters.

In probably most cases the decision-making process would become very ugly (large switch statements, for example), and here more explicit functions and methods would be more descriptive and appropriate.

As mentioned by Steve in the comments, REST could  be an appropriate way to differentiate server-side calls while using a single client-side AJAX function. All that's needed on the client is knowledge of the url to be used.